# Why does the maven versions plugin not recommend a plugin upgrade

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-versions-plugin

According to the [plugin page](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/index.html#) the latest version of the maven dependencies plugin is `3.1.1`.

In my project I see:

> ./mvnw dependency:help | grep "Apache Maven Dependency Plugin"
>   [INFO] Apache Maven Dependency Plugin 2.10

If I run `./mvnw versions:display-plugin-updates | grep -i dependency | wc -l` I see `0`

Indicating that the versions plugin doesn't seem to want to let me know that I could update from 2.10 -> 3.1.1

I am using `Maven 3.5.4`.

If I explicitly add this to my pom then the latest version is used:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</plugin>
```

> ./mvnw dependency:help | grep "Apache Maven Dependency Plugin"
>   [INFO] Apache Maven Dependency Plugin 3.1.1

Is anyone able to educate me as to why this might be? Is it likely misconfiguration in my project or did I misunderstood how `mvn:versions` should work.

Comment: Which version of versions-maven-plugin do you use?

Comment: 2.2, it's being managed by spring boot `1.5.15.RELEASE` https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.15.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L218

Comment: First try calling Maven without maven wrapper and show the full output without filtering via grep etc....